# TWRequest calls on behalf of app?

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm trying to add a feature to allow users to log-in via Facebook/Twitter/Google+ and leave comments in my app. I also want to display the avatars of other users that have left comments.

If the users has previously signed-in with Twitter, I can use TWRequest to call the API using `[request setAccount:self.account]`, but if not, the request returns `"Bad Authentication data"`.

I created an application on Twitter, how I use the consumer key and consumer secret with TWRequest or are those used just for OAuth with a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) with the help of [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) fixed my problem.

```
apiWrapper = [STTwitterAPIWrapper
              twitterAPIApplicationOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"..."
              consumerSecret:@"..."];


[apiWrapper verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *token) {
    DDLogInfo(@"Twitter App logged in with token: %@",token);
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    DDLogCError(@"Twitter verify credentials error %@",error);
}];
```

Comment: The `verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:` callback parameter is the username, not an OAuth token

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [reverse auth.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

The most common use case of reverse auth. is letting users register/login to a remote service with their OS X or iOS Twitter account.

```
iOS/OSX     Twitter     Server
|------------>|             |   reverse auth.
|< - - - - - -|             |   access tokens
|             |             | 
|-------------------------->|   access tokens
|             |
|             |<------------|   access Twitter on user's behalf
|             | - - - - - ->|
```

Here is how to use reverse authentication with [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest):

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerName:nil
                                                          consumerKey:@"CONSUMER_KEY"
                                                       consumerSecret:@"CONSUMER_SECRET"];

[twitter postReverseOAuthTokenRequest:^(NSString *authenticationHeader) {

    STTwitterAPI *twitterAPIOS = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];

    [twitterAPIOS verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        [twitterAPIOS postReverseAuthAccessTokenWithAuthenticationHeader:authenticationHeader
                                                            successBlock:^(NSString *oAuthToken,
                                                                           NSString *oAuthTokenSecret,
                                                                           NSString *userID,
                                                                           NSString *screenName) {

                                                                // use the tokens...

                                                            } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                // ...
                                                            }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: I don't want to log in the user. I just want to download avatars of Twitter users that commented even if the current user decides to login with Facebook or Google but not Twitter, but since I can't make an un-authenticated call to the API, I had to use app-only auth.

Comment: @nst thanks for this! Couldn't find documentation anywhere to retrieve the OAuth tokens, you made my day sir